# Html page does not load (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, redirect, window.location

I've been trying to switch pages from one login page to another. It does not seem to load or am i doing something wrong?

the link of code pen: https://codepen.io/batajusasmit/pen/OJVyGEW

Here is my code.

```
 function validate() {
     var username = document.getElementById('username').value;
     var password = document.getElementById('password').value;

         if (username == 'admin' && password == 'admin') {
             alert('login successful!');
             window.location = 'link.html';
             return false;
            }
          }
```

Comment: `window.location` should be `window.location.href` and also it only accepts full URL. e.g `window.location.href = 'http://yourwebsite/path/link.html'`

Comment: Show your HTML form

Comment: I have updated the code.

Comment: can you add your code in a external code sharing site like https://codepen.io/pen/

Comment: Added code pen link in there.

Comment: So what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: after logging in I should go through and land on a file called link.html. It's all in client side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to stop submission on same page and then go to new location

You have used `validate()` function in button `onclick`. But you should use `return validate()` which will return boolean value to stop form from submitting

```js
function validate() {
 var username = document.getElementById('username').value;
 var password = document.getElementById('password').value;

     if (username == 'admin' && password == 'admin') {
         alert('login successful!');
         window.location = '/'; //change with your location
         return false;
        }
      }
```

```html
<div class="container">
<form>
    <h1 id="form">Login!</h1>
    <div class="login">
        <label class="name">username:</label>
        <input id="username" class="username" type="text" placeholder="name...">

        <label class="pass">password:</label>
        <input id="password" class="password" type="password" placeholder="password...">

    </div>

    <div class="submit">
        <button id="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="return validate()">Submit</button>
    </div>


   </form>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out. I just needed the backslash.

```
 window.location.href = '/link.html';
```